# How to hide events that happened today and have passed ? Symfony

Tags: symfony, time

In my Symfony project, I have created the table "event" and datatime field in it named **start**. In twig, I wish to filter and display upcoming events. So events that have passed would be visible any more.

At the moment, I used `{% if event.start > date() %}`. It worked to hide events that happened days before today. I wanted also to hide events that already happened today but currently it doesn't work when time has passed of the today's event.

How can I hide events that time already has passed ?

Comment: Why not use a datetime field instead if you want to use both date and time together ? Also it would be better to filter in the backend and not in twig. Performance would be bad with a lot of events say 100,000 of them

Comment: As @DylanKAS suggests, filter your resource. You can do this using [`Criteria`](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-collections/en/stable/index.html#selectable-methods) and [`Comparison` (expressions)](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-collections/en/stable/expressions.html#expressions). You can fix this separately and have a larger dataset, and add the Criteria when you want to filter down to current events. The more logic your template implements, coupled with many events not shown, will make your project harder to understand/maintain and run.

Comment: Thank you Jared. At the moment, I to do it this way but I keep that in mind. ;)

Comment: I changed the field which is named "start" and is a datetime field. I updated my description to explain where I am stuck at the moment.

Comment: ```{% if event.start > 'now' %}```was the solution. ^^

Comment: Please share more details, like the code involved. If there are a lot of events, you should not do this in Twig, as you don't want to even load such data into your template

Comment: Thanks Nico Hasse. I think I have just found the solution... I am going to share it as a new answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

better to make a function in the repository and call it in the controller not using findAll and  hide events.

```
// EventRepository
public function eventsList()
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('e')
        ->andWhere('e.date >= :today')
        ->setParameter('today', new \DateTime())
        ->orderBy('e.id', 'DESC')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult()
    ;
}
```

Comment: Thank you hous. This is interesting. The problem is that I need to display the list of events with every date and time. It's in events.twig I wish to filter and display future events.

Comment: Imagine you have 100 events and only 20 events must be shown. With findAll 100 events will be selected from database and filtred in twig. But using query builder and selected only eventd where date greater then today, only 20 events will be selected and you don't need to filter them in the twig

Comment: Ok hous, I will try your solution. So I paste eventsList function in EventRepository. Do I need to do something else ?

Comment: I realize that it will be a problem, because events will be created endlessly and passed events will never be deleted.

Comment: So my question is how can I use this function ? And how can I display the right events on twig file ?

Comment: To use this function , you do as findAll or findBy ... just call it with it's nam in the controller. Replace findAll with the name of this function

Comment: https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#querying-for-objects-the-repository

Comment: Thank you hous. I took your answer into consideration but I think I have found a simpler solution... I posted it in an answer. I hope it will be fine. I am looking forwards your next advices.

Comment: My advice is to not hesitate to create your own queries in the repositories to achieve the results you want. You will nead that in your project one day, so try to learn how to do that and I'll help you when you need

Comment: It took me some time to understand the solution. That worked very well ! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution :

- Make sure the field is datetime.
- Use `{% if event.start > 'now' %}`and it will take into account day (of today) and (current) time.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a better solution (I precise that an address is given to events, and address has a "bigcity" registered, this why I am using LocationRepository) :

EventController.php

```
    #[Route('/events', name: 'events')]
    public function events(
        Request $request, 
        EventRepository $eventRepository, 
        CategoryRepository $categoryRepository,
        BigCityRepository $bigcityRepository,
        LocationRepository $locationRepository
    ){
        $category = $categoryRepository->findOneById($request->query->get('category'));
        $bigcity = $bigcityRepository->findOneById($request->query->get('bigcity'));
        $location = $locationRepository->findAll($request->query->get('location.bigcity'));

        $events = $eventRepository->findBy(['category' => $category, 'address' => $location]);
        return $this->render("front/events.html.twig", [
            'events' => $events,
            'category' => $category,
            'bigcity' => $bigcity
        ]);
    }
```